# iOS UI testing - picker wheel adjusting only swipes by one item

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

I am trying to write a test for UIPickerView to pick certain values. I use `picker.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: pickValue)` to do so. But the problem is that for some reason this only swipes picker by one value.

For example on the gif you can see that initial value was 52, then I called `picker.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "15")` and it became 51 instead of 15, then I called it again and it became 50:

[image: wrong picker behaviour]

So the pattern is that it only changes it by one value up or down closer to the desired value.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code? Much better readable than the screenshot.

Comment: You are pausing during a UI test and giving manual LLDB commands?

Comment: @matt yes. To show interactively how it behaves

Comment: @koen I am calling `adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "15")` on the `pickerWheel element`

Comment: @Simon Moshenko: apple docs say 
   /*! Changes the displayed value for the picker wheel. Will generate a test failure if the specified value is not available. */
    open func adjust(toPickerWheelValue pickerWheelValue: String)
}

is the expected value available? What is the error generated at runtime (not lldb)?
It sure looks like you are calling this correctly to me..

Comment: @ablarg yes, it has the expected value. In fact if I do these actions in a loop, it eventually comes to that value and does nothing from it. So it know that the value is there and the value is correct. Also there is no error while I run the actual tests.

Comment: Sadly, still not fixed as of Aug 31, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing with initial value works for me. So my code looks like this:

```
app.pickerWheels["52"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "15")
```